# Trying to set a relative path in proxy_cache_path in nginx.conf file

Tags: linux, nginx, caching

By default the `proxy_cache_path` in the `nginx.conf` file is: `/var/cache/nginx/` but I want to set it in some place in my local directory.

Suppose my, `nginx.conf` file is in a local directory called service which is in a directory called build. So I want to set the `proxy_cache_path` as `../build/cache/`

This is what I am doing:

```
proxy_cache_path
      # Where to read/write cached files, use the mounted volume
      ../../build/cache/
```

But in the output, I am getting the path as: `usr/share/nginx/../../build/cache/`

How do I solve this and how do I set the path as a relative path?

Comment: why do you need relative path?

Comment: because I want to keep the cache folder in the folder I am keeping the .conf file. The entire path can vary from user to user.

Comment: it is your choice, but I would avoid putting config files near cache mess...